# Paypal - Possible to refund through RESTFUL API using a web_accept

Tags: php, paypal, paypal-rest-sdk

I'm currently looking into the possibility of refunding a web_accept type payment for PayPal.

We accept payments on our website and i'd like to automatically refund a transaction. For example:

I have a web_accept payment: Web Accept Payment Received (Unique Transaction ID #XXXXXXXXX)

`$sale = Sale::get('XXXXXXXXX', $apiContext);`

My refund Sale:get() argument returns: 
`'Got Http response code 404 when accessing https://api.paypal.com/v1/payments/sale/6LN17852AX690712B.'`

Which obviously isn't working. Any chance someone can help me out?

Comment: http://www.kvcodes.com/2016/05/paypal-refund-transaction/

Answer (score 1):

It is not possible to refund a `web_accept` transaction via REST API.
You will get this error

```
name:INVALID_RESOURCE_ID

message:The requested resource ID was not found.
```

So, you will need to use **RefundTransaction** [API](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/api/merchant/RefundTransaction_API_Operation_NVP/) to refund this transaction.